# Python - get text from window

Tags: python, linux, user-interface

I need to get url from URL field in Opera, Firefox and Chromium, and store it to variable. I found some modules (win32gui), but they are all for Windows. Is it possible to do this in Linux?

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029355/python-how-to-get-the-firefoxs-url-bar-content-in-gnu-linux
Seems that DBus is really working...

Answer (score 1):

Consider taking a look at [DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings), to the best of my knowledge this can mitigate installing add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the Firefox Remote Control Extension? See here: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/remote-control/

With it, you can "send any Javascript commands to Firefox in a single line". So, if you have a javascript expression to extract what you want from the page, this might work. There are some limitations on the javascript, see here: http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_frm/thread/6cacc96b42a04e73

Comment: In firefox, I already solved it with MozRepl extension: https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki. But the most important is Opera.