# Python - How to get the Firefox's URL bar content in GNU/Linux?

Tags: python, linux, firefox, gnu

I need to get the content of URL bar (of currently opened tab) of Firefox using Python. I've found few solutions for Windows (using libraries such as pywin32) but I need it for GNU/Linux (if available then multi-platform way is the most preferred, of course). I have also found ways doing it by installing add-on for Firefox but I want user to install only Python and (when it's needed) libraries for it [Python].

Comment: The answer is accepted, can you please elaborate on the solution? I cannot find any information about Firefox exporting any information via D-Bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some luck with DBus, although I don't know if it is provided in a standard install.